# Can FFMPEG perform Sample-aes encryption?

Tags: ffmpeg, aes

I'm trying to convert a local .mp4 video to encrypted HLS AES-128 with ffmpeg. I would like to implement SAMPLE-AES in order to have a playlist looking like this: (one key per segment as opposed to one key for the whole set of segments)

```
> #EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="segment-00000.key"
> 
> #EXTINF:4.458667, segment-00000.ts
> #EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="segment-00001.key"
> 
> #EXTINF:4.010000, segment-00001.ts
> #EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="segment-00002.key"
> 
> #EXTINF:4.458667, segment-000002.ts
> #EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="segment-00003.key"
> 
> #EXTINF:4.010000, segment-00003.ts
```

But I have not found yet how to do it... even in the ffmpeg documentation...

Comment: Not implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, so is there another way (software or online service) capable of doing that ? I have not figured it out in AWS Elastric Transcoder either...